# ExecuteQuery Hangs for unknown reason. Exhausted common solutions

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, prepared-statement, jdbctemplate

The logs stop at logger.warn("Start: preparedStatement.executeQuery()"); and hangs indefinitely. No exception is thrown in the logs. The query doesn't show up in SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST under the info column which would mean the query isn't even executed. I'm able to execute the query in commandline and it takes less than a second to bring back all rows. SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE IN_USE <> 0 returns an empty set so no table is locked. Using JDK 1.8, MySQL 1.6, InnoDB. 
*Edit: This is running on AWS and I noticed a large spike in CPU utilization before the hang.

```
public void setup(StringBuilder sql, String[] args, RowMapper<I> rowMapper) throws SQLException{
    this.rowMapper = rowMapper;
    //Create prepared statement
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    logger.warn("Start: Connection.preparedStatement");
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString(),ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    logger.warn("End: Connection.preparedStatement");
    preparedStatement.setFetchSize(fetchSize);
    //Setting SQL arguments
    int i = 1;
    for(String var: args){
        preparedStatement.setString(i++, var);
    }
    logger.warn("Start: preparedStatement.executeQuery()");
    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    logger.warn("End: preparedStatement.executeQuery()");
}
```

Comment: Since your code looks fine, I suggest that you start in debug mode and freeze all threads, to see where it holds up. Maybe that'll give you some direction.

Comment: Unlogged exception? If your log shows, and the query isn't running on the MySQL end, and the "done" log doesn't show, then something stopped your thread in between those log lines. Thread dump?

Comment: Debugging the application locally was a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. There was a synchronized lock in StatementImpl.class Version 1.5 around line 1373 that was waiting for a lock to come off which is why the thread was hanging. I have multiple result sets open at the same time so I ended up giving each result set it's own connection and setting the fetch size to Integer.MIN_VALUE and the application isn't stuck now.